Programmable gain amp vs op-amp + digipot
I'm currently developing a system where I need a signal amplifier with variable gain.
I'm browsing the market for viable chips, and it looks like I have two options:

Programmable gain amplifier
Regular op-amp with a separate digital potentiometer IC in place of the gain resistors

It seems that there is a large discrepancy in price and resolution of these two options. Monolithic PGAs seem to be expensive and usually have a very limited resolution (about 10 steps). Meanwhile, an op-amp + digipot is generally much cheaper and more resolution is available (128+ steps).
This seems somewhat concerning, as I can't really understand why a PGA would be so much more expensive if the same circuit (op-amp + digipot) can be implemented on a single die.
Are there any specific downsides (other than size) to using a digipot + op-amp rather than a monolithic PGA? If not, why isn't this a commonly available implementation?

good gain setting resistors aren't cheap and you often don't need so many ranges. So rather get 4-8 stable, low noise ranges instead of a digipot.

Please edit your question to call out at least one example PGA and at least one example digipot.  It may be useful for you to design your op-amp + digipot solution, and compare it to the PGA.  If the PGA steps the same number of dB each time, its 10 steps may be better than a digipot's 128 linear steps.

There's another possibility: a multiplying DAC.   This, and the 'digipot', both require that digitized input to set the gain is an option, and most digital devices can do less expensive pulse-width modulation-and-filtering as well.
